# Were door keyholes able to be peered through?

Tags: historical-techniques

Spying and subterfuge in videos games and films sometimes show characters peering through keyholes to see into the room beyond. Was there a point in time at which keyholes were actually manufactured in such a way that you could see through to the adjacent room, or is this just an interesting fantasy mechanism?

Comment: Yes, many locks were designed to be lockable from both sides of the door: such as [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Locks_(security_devices)#/media/File:Detalles_de_la_puerta_de_madera_1.JPG)

Comment: I have lived in places and owned a number of pieces of furniture featuring these locks.

Comment: In 18th century Holkham Hall, Norfolk, England the carpentry is said to be so precise that at night you can look through a keyhole in a closed door at one end of the 300 foot series of state rooms and see light from the far room shining though all the keyholes of all the closed doors.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, such keyholes are still the most common locks in some parts of the world: e.g my front door in the UK. More recent houses tend not to have this kind of lock, but it used to be the standard for house exterior doors.

[image: keyhole]